# PHP Postgres JOIN with LIKE query failing

Tags: php, zend-framework, postgresql

I am trying to figure out a query with postgres, and Im not sure its cause I am used to mysql and postgres doesn't have a `LIKE` query. Or what my deal is. Either way I know its not working and I have no idea why not. Can someone help me out point me in the right direction? I mean ultimately I am trying to make a Zend Database version of this query but, this is the core query I am working with to try and make before I attempt to use zend db class to build it.

```
SELECT 
    org.orgid, 
    org.roleid, 
    users.userid, 
    users.email, 
    users.first_name, 
    users.last_name, 
    users.contact_id, 
    users.state, 
    users.ts, 
    users.altemail, 
    users.unboundid, 
    users.blocked 
FROM mapping AS org 
INNER JOIN my_users AS users ON org.userid = users.userid
WHERE (org.orgid = 'generated-id')
AND (org.roleid LIKE 'partner-%');



ERROR:  operator does not exist: roles ~~ unknown
LINE 17: AND (org.roleid LIKE 'partner-%');
                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `orgid` and `roleid`?

Comment: org and user id's are uuid, not sure what roleid is, when I do `\d table_name` on the table. It looks like its a custom type under the description its "user_roles"

Comment: roleid's themselves look like strings delimited with a dash eg: user-moderator-all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
AND (org.roleid LIKE 'partner-%');
```

to

```
AND (org.roleid::text LIKE 'partner-%');
```

Evidently you are working on the textual representation of the roleid.  this seems like it should work fine except your data types do not match.  By casting to text you ensure that they do.

Note that one important ramification is that indexes on roleid will be useless for such a comparison because they operation is not directly compatible with the type.  This shouldn't be a problem since orgid can still use an index but it is something to think about.  If you want to fix that, you may want to use table methods or other functions to break this down for you.  You can then index function output.

For example you could use a table method as like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION is_partner(mapping) returns bool language sql immutable as $$
    SELECT $1.roleid::text LIKE 'partner-%';
$$;
```

You could then index it with:

```
CREATE INDEX mapping_is_partner_idx ON mapping (is_partner(mapping));
```

You could then change that join condition from

```
AND (org.roleid LIKE 'partner-%');
```

to

```
AND org.is_partner;
```

Note in this case, org is necessary and cannot be added implicitly since it changes org.is_oartner to is_partner(org) using class.method notation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is helpful, but 2 things. First I came into work this morning to find out the field despite it showing stings as the result in a standard query, is actually an `enum`, so now I gotta figure out how to work with that like that. This answer however will work for something else I am doing I think, I do have a question about the create function and create index mentioned, Im not familiar enough with postgres yet to understand how that would work in a query like situation.

Comment: This actually did help completely, my only major problem right now is conforming this to a Zend Database based query, which is giving me trouble, the query works in it of it self now in the command line, just not via Zend, I think I need to use something other than `->where()` for my clause in this case, but not sure, still working on it.